# The inversion question containing the person name

Tags: questions

I'm making the corresponding question for the sentence

> Marion est dans la salle d'attente.

Could you please confirm if below sentences are correct?

- Où est-ce que Marion est dans?
- Où Marion est-elle dans?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike in English, you can't end a sentence with ***dans*** so both of your attempts are incorrect.

Here are various possibilities:

> Où Marion est-elle ?
> Où se trouve Marion ?
> Où est Marion ? (better)

If you really want to keep the ***dans*** but the question sounds odd:

> Dans quoi est Marion ?

In spoken French, inversion is usually avoided:

> Elle est où, Marion ?
> Marion est où ?